# Which process is sending keystrokes?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, x11, keyboard

I have an odd issue where the XTEST keyboard on my PC will randomly send the 255 keycode, which turns on the screen if it's off. I've disabled most suspect programs like KDE Connect, but the issue is still there. Is there any way to see which exact process is responsible for the keystroke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the culprit through the use of `lsof -F c /usr/lib/libXtst.so`, which let me see which processes had the XTEST library loaded to send keystrokes.

As it turned out, the culprit was [bsnes-plus' implementation of suppressing the screensaver](https://github.com/devinacker/bsnes-plus/blob/master/bsnes/ui-qt/platform/platform_x.cpp), which, absurdly enough, runs even when the emulator is paused. Thankfully, it's pretty easy to patch out.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `xev` program for graphic mode - see [the man page of xev](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xev).

On Arch, the package is `xorg-xev`.

Comment: This doesn't specify the device that sent the keystroke, nevermind the specific program. This was the first thing I reached for, but it doesn't solve the problem.